# How to load a yaml directly into a Map<String, Car> with SnakeYAML?

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I would like to load this file (test.yml):

```
Car1:
    countriesSold: [Spain, France, Italy]
    model: Seat
    specs: {color: black, height: 29, with: 29}
Car2:
    countriesSold: [Germany, France]
    model: BMW
    specs: {color: white, height: 11, with: 33}
```

To a `Map<String, Car>`.

All examples I see in the SnaleYAML are always putting the Map object inside another object.

When I try to load my file like this

```
Map<String, Car> load = 
(Map<String, Car>) yaml.load(new ClassPathResource("test.yml").getInputStream());
```

it gets loaded to Map of a Map and everything inside are either Strings of Maps.

I think I need to provide the `Constructor` object and `TypeDescription` objects of my inner types the `Yaml`, but I'm not sure how to do it.
Something like this, but I'm not sure what to put for the root element, which is the Map:

```
TypeDescription mapDesc = new TypeDescription(Map.class);
mapDesc.putMapPropertyType("???", String.class, Car.class);
Constructor constructor = new Constructor(mapDesc);
```

The Car class looks like this:

```
public class Car {

    private String model;
    private Specs specs;
    private List<String> countriesSold = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public Specs getSpecs() {
        return specs;
    }

    public void setSpecs(Specs specs) {
        this.specs = specs;
    }

    public List<String> getCountriesSold() {
        return countriesSold;
    }

    public void setCountriesSold(List<String> countriesSold) {
        this.countriesSold = countriesSold;
    }
}
```

And the Specs class looks like this:

```
public class Specs {

    private int height;
    private int with;

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getWith() {
        return with;
    }

    public void setWith(int with) {
        this.with = with;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing a YAML document with a map at the root using snakeYaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551081/parsing-a-yaml-document-with-a-map-at-the-root-using-snakeyaml)